# Does lettuce support pipelining in redis-cluster?

Tags: java, pipeline, redis-cluster, lettuce

Need to run a batch of commands in redis-cluster mode with lettuce.For commands that should run in one partition, i hope to run them in one node sequentially.

As i know, lettuce can support redis pipelining by set the AutoFlushCommands state to be false. But in redis-cluster mode, the command may be send to different nodes in one partition. Is there any way to avoid the problem?

Answer (score 3):

It does, at least, according to Lettuce:https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/wiki/Pipelining-and-command-flushing

> Command flushing is an advanced topic and in most cases (i.e. unless
>   your use-case is a single-threaded mass import application) you won’t
>   need it as Lettuce uses pipelining by default.

It means, it uses pipelining by default, I don't think this is true or clear, as it also mentions:

> A flush is an expensive system call and impacts performance. Batching,
>   disabling auto-flushing
>
> The AutoFlushCommands state is set per connection and therefore
>   affects all threads using the shared connection. If you want to omit
>   this effect, use dedicated connections. The AutoFlushCommands state
>   cannot be set on pooled connections by the lettuce connection pooling.

Which means, if you want true Redis pipelining http://redis.io/topics/pipelining, you can do that as well with some extra effort.

Comment: April 2023 - Lettuce's own documentation is out of date - https://lettuce.io/core/release/api/io/lettuce/core/api/async/BaseRedisAsyncCommands.html#setAutoFlushCommands-boolean-  disable autoflush on the connection and not the Commands object.